# Find a joint distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are not independent and that $Y$ has a marginal distribution $ Y\thicksim Ber(p)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find a joint distribution of two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are not independent and that $Y$ has a marginal distribution $ Y\thicksim Ber(p)$

The problem I have is that for every X with a certain distribution I propose for this question, it ends up fulfilling that X and Y are independent

Answer (score 1):

How about $Y\sim\text{Ber}(p)$ and $X=Y$?

$X=1-Y$ does it too.

Comment: How can I prove they are fully dependent on the other? Sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: @ErickGR Do you know the definition of the phrase "$X$ and $Y$ are independent"?

Answer (score 1):

> Find **a** joint distribution

This is one of the $\infty$ example you can do

|  | Y=0 | Y=1 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X=0** | 1-p |  | 1-p |
| **X=1** |  | p | p |
| **Total** | **1-p** | **p** | **1** |

This is another one

|  | Y=0 | Y=1 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X=0** | 1-p | p/2 | 1-p/2 |
| **X=1** |  | p/2 | p/2 |
| **Total** | **1-p** | **p** | **1** |

... et cetera et cetera

The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent is immediately shown by the fact that there are some emply cells in the table (the joint distribution)